# Why is my Workflow rule emailing inactive users on record creation but only active ones on record update?

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have a workflow rule that is set up to evaluate on both record creation and when the record is edited.  It has an email alert workflow action that is set up to email all members of a particular Role.

When the record is created, it emails everyone in that role *including inactive users* **but** when the record is edited, it emails everyone *excluding inactive users*.

What could be causing this and what would be the path to ensuring only active users are emailed in both scenarios?

[image: Workflow Rule]

[image: Email Alert]

Comment: It doesn't seem logical, indeed. Just to be sure I'm understanding correctly; could you paste a screenshot of the workflow rule and the email alert action?

Comment: If you ask me, that sounds like a bug. I'm pretty sure inactive users are never supposed to be emailed. Have you contacted support? What did they say?

Comment: @sfdcfox - not contacted them yet. I always like to get a community perspective first in case it's my own "user error" and to see if anyone else is seeing the same.  Next stop will be support case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dug deeper and discovered the cause.

- Creation email was sent 12:42 BST
- **Users were deactivated by another admin 14:53 BST**
- Update email was sent 15:11 BST

So not a bug after all.  My takeaway action - *always remember to check the Setup Audit Trail first...*